# How do I get user name or home dir of the logged-in user when I'm root?

Tags: macos, core-foundation

My app runs as the `root` user, but was launched from the regular (Admin) user, e.g. using the `sudo` command (but not necessarily, i.e. I cannot simply check the env var `SUDO_USER`, for instance).

How can I determine the user name or its homedir that is logged in to the User Interface session?

Is there a Cocoa, Foundation or CoreFoundation function that can give me that information?

Comment: Maybe, if you added a 'parent' variable? Who knows, maybe the code will help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the "HOME" environment variable remains set to the logged-in user, even for apps running under the root user. So, here's how to get the home folder for that user:

```
NSString *homeDir = NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment[@"HOME"];
```